# Handling the keypress event in android

Tags: android, keystroke

Our's is a mobile application developed using ADF mobile browser and myapache trinidad components.
We have a requirement of counting characters entered by the user in a . For it, we call a javascript on the onkeypress event of . The page works fine on iphone but in samsung galaxy, the event seems not to be fired. However, on the press of back and cancel button, the event fires well and displays the counter value. But it doesn't work with any other key. seems there is some issue with the keypad design of the phone. Is there any work around?